# Converting an array of numbers to characters ruby

Tags: ruby

The `to_chr` function is supposed to return the encrypted array but converted to characters. I have tried many things and commented out the ones that didn't work.

```
class Encrypt
  def initialize(code, string)
    @code = code
    @string = string
    @encrypted = []
  end

  def to_byte
    @string.each_byte do |c|
      @encrypted.push(c + @code)
    end
    print @encrypted
  end

  def to_chr
    n = @encrypted.length
    # n.times do |i|
    #   @encrypted.push(i.chr)
    # end
    print @encrypted[0].chr

    # @encrypted.each do |x|
    #   @encrypted.push(x.chr)
    # end
    # print @encrypted
  end
end

goop = Encrypt.new(2, "hello")
goop.to_chr
#=> in `to_chr': undefined method `chr' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: @Stefan [This](https://github.com/Evan-Peterson/Encryption) is the link to the GitHub repo, the to_chr function is supposed to return the encrypted array but converted to characters.

Comment: Well when you run the code off GitHub `@encrypted` is empty, you haven't actually assigned anything to it... so maybe start with that.(do `goop.to_byte` to populate the array) I would also recommend `puts` instead of `print`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create instance of `Encrypted` method, but you set `@code = 2`, `@string = "Hello"` and `@encrypted  = []`. So if you call `@encrypted[0]`, ruby return `nil`.

So you can modify your class like this:

```
class Encrypt
  def initialize(code, string)
    @code, @string, @encrypted = code, string, []
  end

  def to_byte
    @string.each_byte { |c| @encrypted << c + @code }
  end

  def to_chr
    to_byte if @encrypted.empty?

    @encrypted.map(&:chr)
  end
end

goop = Encrypt.new(2, "hello")
p goop.to_chr
# => ["j", "g", "n", "n", "q"]
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
def to_chr
    @encrypted.each do |i|
      print i.chr
    end
    print "\n"
end
```

Make sure to call `to_byte` prior to `to_chr`

```
goop = Encrypt.new(2, "hello")
goop.to_byte
goop.to_chr
```

returns:

`jgnnq`

Comment: `puts @encrypted.map(&:chr)` looks a bit less phpish.

Comment: @mudasobwa that prints each characters on a separate line. You could `join` them or use `pack` instead, i.e. `puts @encrypted.pack('c*')`

Comment: Right, well normally you would store the values somewhere else and not print them. I agree that `puts` is a better option than `print` but I made this down and dirty solution without really worrying about that.